# Update UI on JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2

Is there a way to update UI elements asynchronously in JSF 2? 
For example a person is looking on the screen and some pieces on the screen get updated, when say a batch job changes some value.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions. One is e.g. [a4j:push](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/push.jsf), which is further described [here](http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/richfaces-a4j-poll-and-push-can-do-more-together/).

[IceFaces](http://www.icefaces.org/main/home/) is also known for this. Note that some of the components essentially do polling via AJAX, while others actually use reverse ajax/comet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `<p:poll>` provided by [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml).

Here is a working example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterView.number}" />
    <p:poll interval="3" listener="#{counterView.increment}" update="txt_count" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Better to point to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903816/notification-system-with-ppoll-push A more extensive 'answer'...