# How can i refresh dataTable with push in primeFaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to know how can I update DataTable in index1.xhtml when data change in index2.xhtml
using push...i define socket in index1.xhtml like this:

```
<p:socket channel="/table" onMessage="handle"/>
```

and in bean :

```
public void contract(){
 ....
PushContext pcont=PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
pcont.push("/table",something);
}
```

the thing that i don't know is that how can i update dataTable in javaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function handle() {
          ???
        }
</script>
```

Comment: i use remoteCommand but there is some Error...how can i use pcont.push("/table") without another parameter.i think this make Errors

Comment: What is trigger ? for ex: <p:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{globalCounter.increment}" />

Comment: @RongNK yes.that's a <p:commandBotton>...samples in  [primeFaces/push](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf) are unmeaning

Comment: Does your issue like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903816/notification-system-with-ppoll-push

Comment: If you don't care about performance, i think you can, did you try some solution ?

Comment: like polling..?no.THX

Answer (score 3):

This is a better solution without jQ tricks:

```
<p:socket channel="/table" >
    <p:ajax event="message" update=":datatable" />
</p:socket>
```

And this is a more better solution if you don't wanna lose your filters:

```
<p:socket channel="/table" >
    <p:ajax event="message" oncomplete="PF('datatableWidgetVar').filter()" />
</p:socket>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my simple test, when soclet in 2.xhtml is received event from server, it will fire click event to commandbutton, and this commandbutton(you can invisible this) will update the target you want :
Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "globalCounter")
@SessionScoped // option
public class GlobalCounterBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int count;
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public void increment() {
        count++;
        PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
        pushContext.push("/counter", String.valueOf(count));
    }
}
```

1.xhtml:

```
 <h:body>       
        <h:form id="form">  
            <h:outputText id="out" value="#{globalCounter.count}" styleClass="ui-widget display" />  
        </h:form>  
        <p:socket  onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/counter" />             
    </h:body>
```

2.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="form">  
            <h:outputText id="out" value="#{globalCounter.count}" styleClass="ui-widget display" />  
            <br />  
            <p:commandButton onclick="alert('test')" id="btn" process="@form" value="Click" update="@parent" />  
        </h:form>  

        <p:socket  onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/counter" />  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            function handleMessage(data) { 
                $('#form\\:btn').click();    
            }  
        </script>
```

Comment: I have this error:  SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes. and after that java.lang.NullPointerException: null...these all happens when page load.before click on button!

Comment: maybe i make mistake in configure push servlet...when i add push servlet config in web.xml those errors happens.

Comment: My configuration:<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Then you create 1.xhtml and 2.xhtml in primepush folder in web folder.

Comment: atmosphere-compat-jbossweb-1.1.0.RC1.jar   annotation-detector-3.0.1.jar   atmosphere-compat-tomcat-1.1.0.RC1.jar   atmosphere-compat-tomcat7-1.1.0.RC1.jar  atmosphere-runtime-1.1.0.RC1.jar

Comment: i have all dependency that u write...except annotation-detector-3.0.1.jar

Comment: If you still have issue, i will send you my test project in next week :)

Comment: Hi, this solution is very old I am implementing push notification and in your provided solution `PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();` is getting deprecated method, and having Null Pointer Exception on it

Comment: @Sarz Sorry, I didn't work with jsf for a long time ago.